# Finding values of coefficients for exponential function, based on one point and the value of its integral

Tags: exponential-function, problem-solving

### Context:

My problem is analogous to having $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ priority levels to which I want to associate exponential levels of ressources. The total ressources allocated must be 100% (ideally, this would be exact). Also, I'd like to fix the portion of ressources allocated to the first level (in order to be sure that it wouldn't be set to $0$). As I want the sum of portions to equal 1, this needs to be comprised between $0$ and $\frac 1 n$. If possible, I would also like to be able to tune the growth of the exponential once the first point has been fixed.

### What I've done

I've defined my function $f(x) = c_1 \cdot e^{c_2x} + c_3$ and have summed up my constraints as $(1): c_1 + c_3 = y_0$ and $(2): \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(i) = 1$.
I also formalized my problem as follow:
Find $T(y_0) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that: $\forall y_0 \in [0, \frac 1 n]$, $\forall (c_1, c_2, c_3) \in T(y_0)$,
$
\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  c_1 + c_3 = y_0\\
  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_1 \cdot e^{c_2x} + c_3 = 1
\end{array}\right.\,
$

### What I need

I hope the summary of the problem into the constraints is correct, if not, please do not hesitate to point it out.
Also, if for any reason this would not be possible, this would also be something interesting!
If the first two points are OK, the thing I would need most is help to solve the problem!
Thanks to everyone who will take the time to read!

### EDIT

Thanks to [@abiessu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86846/abiessu)'s comments and by removing $c_3$ (not as useful as I expected it to be), I've obtained $(2^3)$: $\frac {1 - e^{9 \cdot c_2}} {1 - e^{c_2}} = \frac {1} {c_1}$, but I am stuck here at the moment, and don't know how to get $c_2$ as a function of $c_1$.

### EDIT 2

By substituting $X=e^{c_2}, c_2 \neq 0$, we get $(2^4)$: $\frac {1 - X^9} {1 - X} = \frac {1} {c_1}$. Let's define $g(x)=\frac {1 - x^9} {1 - x}$.
There should be some solution to this problem, seeing as $g$ is defined on $[\sqrt[9]1; 1[$ (not the whole domain), and that $g(\sqrt[9]1)=0$ and $lim_{x \rightarrow 1}g(x) = +\infty$. So, according to the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\forall c_1 \in ]0; +\infty[, \exists c_2 \in [e^{\sqrt[9]1}; e^1]$ s.t. $\frac {1 - e^{9 \cdot c_2}} {1 - e^{c_2}} = \frac {1} {c_1}$.
This is nice to know (if it is even correct), but this isn't making me closer to the solution...

Comment: Did you know that $ae^{bx}=e^{bx+c}$ with $c=\ln a$?  This doesn't exactly take away the $c_1$ constant you have, but it does give you a linear function in the exponent in place of separated constants.  Also, you have $\sum ae^{bx}=1-nc$ since $c=c_3$ is constant, so you can just about choose any $c_3$ you want.

Comment: One guaranteed solution (trivial) is that $c_3=\frac 1n,c_1=0$, so we know that at least one solution to the problem exists.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would equate to $\forall (c_1, c_2, c_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\exists (c_1', c_2') \in \mathbb{R}^2$ s.t. $c_1 \cdot e^{c_2 \cdot x} + c_3 = c_1'  \cdot e^{c_2' \cdot x}$. Is this equivalent to what you said? And most importantly, is this really valid?

Comment: I my previous understanding is correct, as I don't really need to identify $c_3$ but only wanted to use it because I thought it would widen the available shapes for my function, then I will remove it. This would first lead to $f(x) = c_1 \cdot e^{c_2 \cdot x}$, which lead to $(1)$ rewritten as $(1'): c_1 = y_0$. Then $(2)$ can be rewritten as $(2'): \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_1 \cdot e^{c_2 \cdot k} = 1$, then simplified into $(2"): \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{c_2 \cdot k} = \frac 1 {c_1}$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Not quite what I was saying, but yes you can choose $c_3=0$ to make the problem simpler.  And your reduction of that is correct, so you only need to address your equation $(2")$.

Comment: And note, with those reductions, the equation $(2")$ is a geometric series, with all the simplifications and properties available to that type of sum.

Comment: By focusing on $(2")$, I've obtained $(2^3)$: $\frac {1-e^{9 \cdot c_2}} {1-e^{c_2}} = \frac 1 {c_1}$. This said, I am now stuck with this and don't know how to express $c_2$ as a function of $c_1$. Is the transformation from $(2")$ to $(2^3)$ correct? If yes, how can I proceed further?